# Moving a marker along a line, React native, Mapbox or react native maps

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-native-maps

I am going to be displaying the movement of several markers along their respective paths. I have an array of coordinates for each marker.

marker1=[[lan1,lon1],[lan2,lon2],[lan3,lon3],[lan4,lon4],....]

I have managed to draw a line layer for the coordinates but I need to animate the marker to move along it from the starting position until the destination.

I also have more information such as the time stamp for every coordinate recorded. I am using Mapbox, but the solution for react-native-maps would help as well!

Comment: i'll be happy with code in which you have manged to draw a line on mapbox react native.could you please share the code.

Comment: In your state, have a variable that is a geojson of type linestring. This takes more than two coordinates, which is basically the number of points you are passing the line through.

What the "awesome" mapbox documentation neglects to mention when they show you the polyline tag is that you need to wrap it in a shapeSource tag under the MapboxGL tag. 

In this.state I put a geojson variable called route. This is how you draw it

          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id='line1' shape={this.state.route}>
            <MapboxGL.LineLayer id='linelayer1' />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>

Comment: please,give me the  code part of inserting the routes with cordinates and making it geojson of type linestring.if you are kind enough give me googledrive link below as a comment which contains the code

Comment: @Amalp you should pose this as a question so everyone can benefit from the answer in the future. I already explained all of it but I can post a full example as an answer and not a comment. This is not how the platform is supposed to be used.

Comment: I have already posted a question here is the link post it as a answer please iam desperate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878646/draw-a-line-between-two-markers-map-box-react-native

Answer (score 0):

For the animation you need roughly two things:

1. The marker position along its path. You already have the starting and destination positions, so you can use [`Turf.along(line, distance`](http://turfjs.org/docs#along) to have a step by step position.
2. The animation. With [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or even [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) you can update the marker position every x seconds (you could vary it with your timestamps) with the next position (that you get by incrementing the `distance` argument).

You can find a full example on the [Mapbox GL JS examples](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/).

Comment: I’ve seen that example but I’m using react native. Also the examples on their react native github page is not documented so I was not able to understand it. Can you show me an example of how to use it? Simply giving it two positions, how would you animate it?

Comment: I don't know React Native but I guess you could use [Timers](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) for the 2nd step.