# Draw a line between two markers map-box react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mapbox, polyline

I was able to achieve creating a `marker`(annotation) on the map using the below code in `react-native`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapboxGL from '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl';
import Mapbox from '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl';


const columbusCircleCoordinates = [
  -73.98197650909422, 40.768793007758816
];

Mapbox.setAccessToken('your access key');

export default class App extends Component {

  renderAnnotations () {
    return (
      <Mapbox.PointAnnotation
        key='pointAnnotation'
        id='pointAnnotation'
        coordinate={[11.254, 43.772]}>

        <View style={styles.annotationContainer}>
          <View style={styles.annotationFill} />
        </View>
        <Mapbox.Callout title='Look! An annotation!' />
      </Mapbox.PointAnnotation>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Mapbox.MapView
            styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Street}
            zoomLevel={15}
            centerCoordinate={[11.256, 43.770]}
            showUserLocation={true}
            style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderAnnotations()}
        </Mapbox.MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  annotationContainer: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  annotationFill: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    transform: [{ scale: 0.6 }],
  }
});
```

But from the tutorials i figured out that we are able to draw `polylines` on `mapbox` using `<MapboxGL.LineLayer />`. But there is proper example on how to do this.

Can someone please provide with me a sample `code` how to draw a `line` between two annotations on `mapbox` `react-native`.

Comment: Please tell me you changed your mapbox token after posting this question. Anyone can grab that and use it :)

Comment: yes i changed it way back... don't worry :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like I shared in my previous answer: In your state, have a variable that is a geojson of type linestring. This takes more than two coordinates, which is basically the number of points you are passing the line through. What the "awesome" mapbox documentation neglects to mention when they show you the polyline tag is that you need to wrap it in a shapeSource tag under the MapboxGL tag. In this.state I put a geojson variable called route. Maybe it will make more sense with the below code sample:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {


 Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import MapboxGL from '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken('your access key');

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      route:
        {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
            {
              "type": "Feature",
              "properties": {},
              "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                  [
                    11.953125,
                    39.436192999314095
                  ],
                  [
                    18.896484375,
                    46.37725420510028
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },   
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView
          styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Light}
          zoomLevel={15}
          centerCoordinate={[11.256, 43.770]}
          style={styles.container}> 
          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id='line1' shape={this.state.route}>
            <MapboxGL.LineLayer id='linelayer1' style={{lineColor:'red'}} />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>

        </MapboxGL.MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: just a reminder the shape property only accepts array of coordinates...And it has to be converted into linestring...The above code will crash.

Comment: Hey @ウィエム can u please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266242/directions-between-two-point-location-in-mapbox-gl-react-native) it's based on our code, Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you get a feature collection for a path between start point and destination point using mapbox api? are you using `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk` npm package??